# How to open a .HM file in Windows7?

Tags: windows, file-extension

I've been sent a document as a `.HM` file, this is [most likely](http://filext.com/file-extension/HM) an "Unknown Apple II File" rather than "Windows Help Context IDs" (used by MAKEHM.EXE.)

Are there any other applications that save documents as `.HM`s?

---

It's worth requesting the document in another, known format before finding out what a `.HM` file is.

Comment: Try to open the document in a normal text editor - what do you see? Why can't you ask the person who sent you the file what it is?

Comment: @slhck a lot of random ASCII, a couple of meaningful paragraphs and some XML.